how to include brackets in pointform latex
I want to generate following point form with brackets in each item:

this is the latex code I used:
\section{Timeline}
\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
\item [{[Month 1–2]}] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\item [{[Month 3–4]}] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\item [{[Month 5–6]}] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\item [{[Month 7–8]}] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\item [{[Month 9–11]}] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\item [{[Month 12]}] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\end{itemize}

but the generated text was like:

how to update the latex code in correct format

You need
\item {[Month 1–2]}

or
\item {}[Month 1–2]

so the text is not seen as the optional argument to \item

Laziest!
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mitem}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}m}{%
  \makemitem#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makemitem}{mm}{%
  \item\relax[\IfValueTF{#2}{Months}{Month} #1\IfValueT{#2}{--#2}] -- \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\section{Timeline}

\begin{itemize}
\mitem{1-2} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\mitem{3-4} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\mitem{5-6} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\mitem{7-8} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\mitem{9-11} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\mitem{12} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


The argument to \mitem is split at - returning
{<before hyphen>}{<after hyphen>}

but, if no hyphen is found, the second braced group will contain the special string -NoValue-, which can be tested in the \makemitem command to take decisions.
With \relax we stop \item to look for an optional argument.

Working with David's answer here are some ways to do it:

The first two items are just as David described: this approach results in some kind of unaligned text:
    \item {} [Month 1-9] Some text
    \item {} [Month 10-20] Some text

From a refactoring point of view it may be nice to absorb the beginning and just pass the actual range of months - more unified code, same result after compile:
\newcommand\montha[1]{{} [Month #1]}
...
    \item \montha{1-9} Some text, absorbed
    \item \montha{10-20} Some text, absorbed

If you want to introduce some kind of alignement here's a simple approach:

use a \makebox with fixed width
inside use \hfill to 'push' the two text componenents apart
follow the same approach, else

\newcommand\monthb[1]{{} \makebox[22mm]{[Month \hfill#1]}}
...
    \item \monthb{1-9} Some text, even more absorbed
    \item \monthb{10-20} Some text, even moreabsorbed



\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\montha[1]{{} [Month #1]}
\newcommand\monthb[1]{{} \makebox[22mm]{[Month \hfill#1]}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}
    \item {} [Month 1-9] Some text
    \item {} [Month 10-20] Some text
    \item \montha{1-9} Some text, absorbed
    \item \montha{10-20} Some text, absorbed
    \item \monthb{1-9} Some text, even more absorbed
    \item \monthb{10-20} Some text, even moreabsorbed
 \end{itemize}
\end{document}


P.S.: Those lazy refactor guys may even absorb the \item ...
\newcommand\mitem[1]{\item {} \makebox[22mm]{[Month \hfill#1]}}
...
    \item \monthb{10-20} Some text, even moreabsorbed
    \mitem {1-8} Here we go
 \end{itemize}


